# Создание элементов UI в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть префаб кнопки. Нужно чтобы эта кнопка появлялась в интерфейсе при взаимодействие персонажа с предметом, например при подборе предмета. Вопрос именно в том как эту кнопку отобразить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как самый очевидный вариант сделать так: заранее создаете кнопку на сцене (`Game Object/UI/Button` или для какого-нибудь объекта `Add Component/UI/Button`), настраиваете её как вам нужно, а затем выключаете её прямо в окне испектора (`Inspector`), там слева сверху галочка. 
Затем, в нужный вам момент включаете её, т.е. в вашем случае - это в соответствующем методе класса (например, для соприкосновения `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collideObject)`, который находится в навешанном на данный объект скрипте, выполнить что-то в духе (ну или чтобы не делать `Find` заранее побеспокойтесь о том, чтобы ссылка ну данную кнопку уже имелась у объекта, метод которого вызовется):

```
GameObject.Find("YourButtonGameObjectName").SetActive(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если конкретно "Создание", то так:

```
T obj = Instantiate(prefab) as T;
obj.transform.SetParent(parent, false);
```